# A possible theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

So i was playing around with members of a random power set, and i came to a revelation(at least to me it was). Say $A=\{1,2,3\}$ then for arbitrary $k,n\in Z^+$, $n=|A|$ and $\mathscr{P}(A)=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$, $|\mathscr{P}(A)|=2^n.$ There are ${n\choose n-1}$ ways of choosing ($n-1$)- element sets in $\mathscr{P}(A)$  so that's ${3\choose1}+{3\choose2}+{3\choose3}=7$ so we're short by one, playing around once more and we have    $2{n\choose n}+{n\choose n-1}+{n\choose n-2}=2^n$ and by generalizing:
$2{n\choose n}+{n\choose k}+...+{n\choose k-(n-2)}=2^n$ for $1\le k\le n-1$.

Pardon my ignorance, but is there a theorem for this(if the equation is correct), and is this how research in math is done(if it is, then it must be pretty darn exciting!!!)

Comment: Are you claiming that $2\binom{n}{n}+\binom{n}{n-1} + \binom{n}{n-2} = 2^n$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z_+$?

Comment: If they're not please show me some counter-examples

Comment: @pkjag ??? `n=4`.

Comment: But that's not my general formula, my main emphasis is on the last formula

Comment: What is ${n\choose k-(n-2)}$ if $k\leqslant n-1$? This seems to make sense only when $k=n-1$, in which case this is the formula in my answer, or when $k=n-2$, in which case this is wrong.

Comment: Are we okay now??

Comment: No we are not "okay" (and you seem quite intent in NOT reading the page I linked to).

Comment: So if i add the clause 'for all $n\lt4$' can it be made into a theorem then??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sums you suggest are not $2^n$ (maybe check a few simple cases?), the actual identity being
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}=2^n.
$$
This is a case of the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), which states that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k=(x+1)^n,
$$ 
and, more generally, that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^ky^{n-k}=(x+y)^n.
$$
Happy reading!

Comment: Did did nice here! +1

Comment: Did always does nice :P +1

Comment: So if wanted to show that the sums are equal to the number of elements in a power set would i need to generalize into the Binomial theorem, or could i create my own theorem  to say so??

Comment: @pkjag Did you read the WP page I linked to?

Comment: @Theta30 Because I am mean. Or the opposite. :-)

Comment: @Theta30 am a he, while it may not be a new theorem, the experience was golden